# Splitting up lines in a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to break up a long regex into smaller chunks. Is it possible/good practice to change A to B?

**A:**

```
line = re.sub(r'\$\{([0-9]+)\}|\$([0-9]+)|\$\{(\w+?\=\w?+)\}|[^\\]\$(\w[^-]+)|[^\\]\$\{(\w[^-]+)\}',replace,line)
```

**B:**

```
line = re.sub(r'\$\{([0-9]+)\}|'
              r'\$([0-9]+)|'
              r'\$\{(\w+?\=\w?+)\}|'
              r'[^\\]\$(\w[^-]+)|'
              r'[^\\]\$\{(\w[^-]+)\}',replace,line)
```

**Edit:**

I receive the following error when running this in Python 2:

```
def main():
while(1):
    line = raw_input("(%s)$ " % ncmd)
    line = re.sub(r'''
                    \$\{([0-9]+)\}|
                    \$([0-9]+)|
                    \$\{(\w+?\=\w?+)\}|
                    [^\\]\$(\w[^-]+)|
                    [^\\]\$\{(\w[^-]+)\}
                  ''',replace,line,re.VERBOSE)
    print '>> ' + line
```

**Error:**

```
(1)$ abc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 4, in <module>
    main()
  File "Test.py", line 2, in main
    [^\\]\$\{(\w[^-]+)\}''',replace,line,re.VERBOSE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: multiple repeat
```

Comment: As far as I know, this is used often, sometimes with additional comments on each line explaining the regex part.

Comment: You'd be better off using `expanded` mode. Also your regex has problems. For instance `\$(\w[^-]+)` and `\$\{(\w[^-]+)\}` are open ended.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [triple-quoted (multi-line) string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) and set the [`re.VERBOSE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) flag, which allows you to break a Regex pattern over multiple lines:

```
line = re.sub(r'''
\$\{([0-9]+)\}|
\$([0-9]+)|
\$\{(\w+?\=\w?+)\}|
[^\\]\$(\w[^-]+)|
[^\\]\$\{(\w[^-]+)\}
''', replace, line, re.VERBOSE)
```

You can even include comments directly inside the string:

```
line = re.sub(r'''
\$\{([0-9]+)\}|             # Pattern 1
\$([0-9]+)|                 # Pattern 2
\$\{(\w+?\=\w?+)\}|         # Pattern 3
[^\\]\$(\w[^-]+)|           # Pattern 4
[^\\]\$\{(\w[^-]+)\}        # Pattern 5
''', replace, line, re.VERBOSE)
```

Lastly, it should be noted that you can likewise activate the verbose flag by using `re.X` or by placing `(?x)` at the start of your Regex pattern.

Comment: what is the triple ''' for?

Comment: @asfadsfaf - You need that to have a string literal span multiple lines.  Give me a second and I'll include a docs link.

Comment: @iCodez I'm receiving a strange error when trying this, would you mind taking a look at my edit? Thank you.

Comment: @asfadsfaf - The pattern I labeled "Pattern 3" has invalid syntax.  Specifically, `?+` is incorrect and should be written as `+?`.

Comment: @iCodez now it runs, but it doesn't match anything anymore. Should I post another question or do you have an idea of why this might not be working? For example, it doesn't match $2

Comment: @asfadsfaf - Huh.  I'm not sure why it is doing that.  As you can see in the link, the code for the verbose mode is correct.  Maybe it is something to do with the patterns you are using.  Anyways, I found it works if you remove `re.VERBOSE` and instead start the pattern with `r'''(?x)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also separate your expression over multiple lines using double quotes, like the following:

```
line = re.sub(r"\$\{([0-9]+)\}|\$([0-9]+)|"
              r"\$\{(.+-.+)\}|"
              r"\$\{(\w+?\=\w+?)\}|"
              r"\$(\w[^-]+)|\$\{(\w[^-]+)\}",replace,line)
```